# Golang - Where does the function "Execute" writes to the stream?

Tags: stream, go

i´m beginner in Go and i dont understand where is the call to write the data "home.html" in the stream of the function `Execute`.The http.ResponseWriter is the writter thats clear but in the function `Execute` i cant see anything like `write .. fmt.Fprint..` i only see the recursion of `Execute`

http://golang.org/src/pkg/html/template/template.go?s=1245:1315#L40

```
//my Function
func homeHandler(c http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

var homeTempl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("home.html"))

//here is my misunderstanding
homeTempl.Execute(c, req.Host)
//Thats consistent 
fmt.Fprint(c, "hallo")

}
```

Comment: It's not recursion. html/template uses text/template

Comment: yes thats was my misunderstanding. it is written in text/template in the `walk` method http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/exec.go?s=2630:2700#L95  s.wr.Write(n.Text);

Answer (score 1):

That's not a recursive call. It is calling Template.Execute in the "text/template" package (not Template.Execute in "html/template"). That is also where you will find the code that actually writes bytes on the Writer.

http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/exec.go?s=2630:2700#L95